# How to get folder size of a Large Directory in Linux

Tags: linux, directory

I've tried scheduling a script in the backend in the server du -sch for that archieve folder its running for almost 2 days still the size is not extracted. For other folders yes but only for this folder due to size i guess not extracted. I tried ls -f, ls -l |wc -l no output takes time and in the end no output.

I was assigned this task still i am clueless on how to achieve it.

Comment: 9 million files in that directory

Comment: Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*